# Python login paypal with Requests

Tags: python, paypal, python-requests

i want to print dashboard html source after successful login in paypal, Here is my full code

```
import requests
import lxml.html

# Get Auth & Login URL
get_login = requests.get('https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run')
get_login_response = get_login.text.encode('utf-8') #printing html source
get_login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(get_login_response) #printing <Element html at 0x7f19cb242ec0>
auth = get_login_html.xpath("//input[@name='auth']/@value") #printing [<InputElement 7fb0971e9f18 name='auth' type='hidden'>]
login_url = get_login_html.xpath("//form[@name='login_form']/@action")

# Post Login
payload = {
'login_cmd':'',
'login_params':'',
'login_email':'websec@spam4.me',
'login_password':'jancok666',
'auth':auth[0],
'submit.x':'Log In',
'form_charset':'UTF-8',
'browser_name':'Firefox',
'browser_version':'18',
'browser_version_full':'18.0'
}
post_login = requests.post(login_url[0], data=payload)
post_login_response = post_login.text.encode('utf-8')

print post_login_response
```

but what i get is html source of captcha challenge like this

```
......... <h1 class="headerText">Security Challenge</h1><p>Type the characters you see in the image for security purposes.</p>
```

[image: Security Image]

So how i can print dashboard html source after successful login ? whats wrong with my code ? Thank you very much :D

Comment: Paypal has an API to access your data. They don't don't you to scrape the page. It would be a security risk to the customers to allow that. So they put several measures in place to prevent scraping. Use the API!

Comment: Just to second what Klaus says: your code does not have a specific error, it is trying to do something that violates PayPal's user agreement & security policies. PayPal is detecting that you are an automated agent, not a human, and blocking access this way. Don't try it. Not only will PayPal take a variety to steps to block you, but you will potentially be in legal jeopardy as well.

Comment: @KlausD. What about if i create little application which can check PayPal balance but in this case is mass balance check , so i have email and password lists, lets assume 5 email and password, so the algorithm is get first line email and pass > check balance > print balance , then second line email and pass > check balance > print balance, and so on till finish, is it possible with API ? thanks.

Comment: I guess there will be some limitation on how many accounts you can check from one IP in a time frame. And there might be some restrictions in the Terms and Conditions of Paypal. But if you check just five accounts once per hour here should be no problem. If you have the need to be informed more often about an account's changes, the API also provides solutions for that: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/ .

Comment: You do know that PayPal has secure ways to do this, right? There is a CheckBalance API and everything, and you DO NOT NEED to violate PayPal's terms of service by collecting PayPal passwords to use it. Again (and as I wrote on your other, duplicate question that you asked the next day) this is absolutely forbidden by PayPal's TOS and is not OK with PayPal at any volume level. Any automated PayPal login will be fought tooth & nail by PayPal, with good reason. Abandon this line of effort, it is not legitimate (nor, I suspect, are you).

Comment: @geewiz I checked paypal API. It doesn't up-to-date with data from website. Sometime it delay up to 8 hours, check this : https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Payments/REST-Sync-API-Payments-do-not-show-up-until-several-HOURS-later/td-p/1523372 . I also tried webhook, it almost works fine but sometime it miss a transaction. That's why I also want to login and get data like a browser.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use proxy so that the request wont be from one ip address to avoid reCAPTCHA

```
import requests
import lxml.html

# Get Auth & Login URL
get_login = requests.get('https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-run')
get_login_response = get_login.text.encode('utf-8') #printing html source
get_login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(get_login_response) #printing <Element html at 0x7f19cb242ec0>
auth = get_login_html.xpath("//input[@name='auth']/@value") #printing [<InputElement 7fb0971e9f18 name='auth' type='hidden'>]
login_url = get_login_html.xpath("//form[@name='login_form']/@action")

# Post Login
payload = {
'login_cmd':'',
'login_params':'',
'login_email':'websec@spam4.me',
'login_password':'jancok666',
'auth':auth[0],
'submit.x':'Log In',
'form_charset':'UTF-8',
'browser_name':'Firefox',
'browser_version':'18',
'browser_version_full':'18.0'
}

#proxy
proxy = {
 'https': '1.2.3.4:1234',
 'http': '1.2.3.4:1234'
}
post_login = requests.post(login_url[0], data=payload, proxies=proxy)
post_login_response = post_login.text.encode('utf-8')

print post_login_response
```

LIKE SO, YOU SHOULDNT GET CAPTCHA AGAIN.... :)